# how to hide keyboard in react-native-pell-rich-editor without losing focus?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i want to hide keyboard to pick smilies but keyboard is not hiding in react-native-pell-rich-editor because when i hide keyboard using blurContentEditor() method then i loose focus and i cant add smilies in input box. so is there any method to hide Keyboard.

Keyboard.dismiss is not working here.

because it causes both smilies picker and keyboard opened.

here is the screen shot.

[image]

```
 <RichEditor
                    ref={rf => this.richText = rf}
                    initialContentHTML={this.state.PostDescription}
                    editorInitializedCallback={()=>{
               this.richText.focusContentEditor()

                    }}
                    style={{
                      // minHeight:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 30 : 40,
                      // maxHeight:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100: 40,
                      height:'100%',
                      backgroundColor:'white',
                      flex: 1,justifyContent:'center',
                      minWidth:'100%',width:'100%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The prop `showSoftInputOnFocus={false}` works this way on a `TextInput` component, try using this on your component.

Comment: I am not using textinput . I am using a react-native-pell-richeditor

Comment: @Wiliam Brochensque junior How can I do this on iOS?